# How do I prevent the LED lights from pulsing on a B450 Tomahawk Max?

Tags: linux, hardware

I have a B450 Tomahawk Max running Ubuntu, and I downloaded [this program](https://github.com/nagisa/msi-rgb)
to control the built-in LED lights. When I try to display solid color, it pulses on and off.

For example,
`sudo ./target/release/msi-rgb 00000000 00000000 FFFFFFFF -ir -ig -ib` 
will make the LEDs pulse blue instead of showing solid blue like it's supposed to.

How do I make the LEDs show a solid color? Is it possible through `msi-rgb`, or do I need to use a different program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this comment](https://github.com/nagisa/msi-rgb/issues/108#issuecomment-643611628) on a related issue in the repo, I found the following solution:

```
sudo ./target/release/msi-rgb 0 0 0 -ig -ib # provides a static red
sudo ./target/release/msi-rgb 0 0 0 -ir -ig # provides a static blue
sudo ./target/release/msi-rgb 0 0 0 -ir -ig # provides a static green
```

Comment: Looks like this special behavior requiring the inversion of the other two colors is specific to the B450 Tomahawk Max.